# Live template shortcut overridden by smart type completion

Tags: intellij-idea

In previous versions of IntelliJ I would always set up my own live template for JUnit test methods. Like so:

```
@Test
public void should$DO_WHAT_NOW$() {
    $END$
}
```

Then I would map this to the keyword `test` and when I typed test+TAB it would expand into the template. It worked a treat.

However, in v12 the IDE seems to prefer to expand on tab to a type. For example, I type `test`+TAB and the IDE changes this to the first fuzzy-matched type it can find. e.g. `BusinessWidgetTest`. I can't seem to enable the live template functionality for my user-template.

What has changed? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have enabled the "applicable in" contexts to Java and it had no effect. I even enabled it "Everywhere" as a test, but this didn't work either.

EDIT: I changed `expand with` from `Default (tab)` to `Enter` and it started working. Then I changed it back to `Default (tab)` and it continued to work. Perhaps it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I believe IDEA 12 changed the way you pick what a template "applies to", and by default, they seem to apply to nothing. Under the "Template text" area, you should see either "No applicable contexts." or "Applicable in <something>." along with a link that lets you pick what contexts (i.e. kinds of files or language parts) the template should apply in. Make sure to select "Java" or some part of it if that's what you want.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention. I've done that. It doesn't have any effect on this problem.

Comment: I just tested your template in IDEA 12.0.1 (build IU-123.94), and it works fine when I pick "Java" as the "applies to". You don't happen to be using an EAP, where a bug might have crept in?